# Ruby on Rails: controller action cannot display notice alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found this weird problem in my app. When user is trying to edit the article and do it wrong, e.g not passing model validations then my update action do not send flash message to the view. Even if it shoud do it:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html do
          redirect_to article_path,
            notice: 'Article has been updated'
        end
      else
        format.html do
          render :edit,
            notice: "Article couldn't be updated. Please try again" //this is what should be send to the view
        end
      end
    end
```

Flash render in application.html.erb:

```
 <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <%= value %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
 <% end %>
```

In this case, when I type <%= flash.inspect %> I also get an empty hash:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x00007fa5c05fcd60 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={}, @now=nil>
```

What make this situtation weird is that my flash alerts works fine in any other cases. E.g. when update action passes validations 'Article has been updated' message is displayed. Only in this case it cannot be done. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have any actions on that model that might be interrupting it? If the validations fail will it do the correct action and show the edit page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flash.now` instead

```
  ....
  else
    format.html do
      flash.now[:alert] = "Article couldn't be updated. Please try again"
      render :edit
    end
  end
```

[flash.now](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#flash-now)